# jquery jsonp request is not getting a callback parameter added properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

I have an object containing UPC codes and I'm iterating through them, hitting a server for product info on each via jsonp requests:

```
$.each( obj, function( key, val ){
    var requestUrl = 'https://domain.com/products/' + val.upcCode + '/prices';
    $.ajax({
        url : requestUrl,
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        success : function(responseData){
            console.log( responseData );
        }
    });
});
```

This works except for that the first request is not getting a callback parameter added properly. All the other requests get

```
&callback=jQuery111108732157719514818_1411587984724&_=1411587984725
```

(or similar) appended but the first is only getting

```
&true=jsonp&_=1411587984723
```

So the server doesn't get a callback and just returns json. Has anybody seen jQuery doing this?

Comment: are you sure it's jquery screwing up, and not some server-side redirect re-writing the url that jquery generated?

Comment: That is certainly a possibility, the server maintainer does love their redirects. Hm. Well, I pasted the bad url in a browser and corrected the callback and it didn't redirect and also correctly returned the jsonp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer appears to be that I had made a separate, earlier jsonp request wherein I manually set the jsonpCallback value to 'jsonp':

```
$.ajax({
    url : '/logic/under29.js',
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback : 'jsonp',
    success : function(response){
        console.log( response);
        logic = response;
    }
});
```

Name that callback anything else and the second jsonp request works. Name it "jsonp" and you get the problem described above.

(jquery 1.11.1)